# creating mesh and matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mesh

How you can see i created a mesh.
Is there any possibility to output the intercept Points? And put in into a matrix?

Im very new in programming, so i hope this isnt a stupid question.

```
import numpy

start = 0
end = 1
bigstep = 0.1

refinedstart = 0.4
refinedend = 0.6
smallstep = 0.01

x = numpy.concatenate([numpy.arange(start, refinedstart, bigstep),
                       numpy.arange(refinedstart, refinedend, smallstep),
                       numpy.arange(refinedend, end, bigstep)])
```

Comment: I do not understand what is your problem. How does the expected output look like?

Comment: IIUC, what you want is `np.meshgrid(x,x)`